# How to render a @FormElement in Views area plugin

Tags: views, theming, 8, forms

I am doing a custom plugin area for displaying some data in a views footer (Drupal 8).

I do something about just like this : [Create a custom area plugin](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203438/create-a-custom-area-plugin)

The only point is, instead of `#markup` in the return array of `render()` method, I would like to return some more complex stuff.
If I try to return a textfield if works:

```
return  [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
];
```

If I try another form API element (defined via a `@FormElement`): it does not render.

```
return  [
  '#type' => 'datetime',
];
```

Two questions:

- Should it render ?
- If not, I can render a block there using this ([ViewsBlockArea](https://github.com/leonk/views_block_area/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Plugin/views/area/ViewsBlockArea.php)) how to do the equivalent but with a `FormElement` instead ? (actually rendering a form API render array.)

EDIT: Here a the finality of what I want to render:

```
$element['form'] = [
  '#type' => 'commerce_coupon_redemption_form',
  '#order_id' => $order->id(),
  '#cardinality' => 1,
  '#element_ajax' => [
    [get_class($this), 'ajaxRefreshSummary'],
  ],
];
```

But you may see that more trivial render array like the datetime one given above does not work either.

Also notice that any element defined by a `@FormElement` annotation from within the namespace `Drupal\Core\Render\Element` is okay.
But `@FormElement` "from elsewhere" like `datetime` does not render.

Comment: Can you post your entire code. The commerce_coupon_redemption_form requires the order_id to be set. Do you provide that?

Comment: I just edited the question to clarify with your request.

Comment: Ah, I see you edited the question just as I was writing my comment. It is often better to provide full code than some stripped pseudo code as important things tend to be left out, hence my question. It is much better like this :)

Comment: If you want to render it as a form, don't you want to wrap it into a call to ```\Drupal::formBuilder()``` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can create block Form first. And from View UI, add a view object to your header or footer. And from View object configuration choose the form block you created.