# Which hook_view_ is always executed and never cached?

Tags: views, 8, hooks

In D8.6 I have problems with counting in a view. After the counting a message in the site should display the total. The message is sometimes show and sometimes not.

I used several different view hooks as some are not executed after caching. Therefore I used the [list with all hooks for views](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/8.6.x)

```
function nvgh_views_post_render(ViewExecutable $view) {

  $result = $view->result;
  $total = 0;

  foreach ($result as $row => $rowinfo) {
    // kint($rowinfo->nid);
      $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($rowinfo->nid);
      $total = $total + $node->get('field_pe_punten')->value;
      // $pe_punten = $node->get('field_pe_punten')->value;
  }

  drupal_set_message('Het totale aantal punten bedraagt voor dit overzicht: ' . $total, 'status', TRUE);

}
```

Which hook should I use in orde to see the message every time?

Comment: There is none. Don't use drupal_set_message(). Prepare it in preprocess, e.g. with hook_preprocess_view() and then display it in a twig template, so it can be cached together with the view

Comment: Hi Berdir, thxs I do not understand the caching different in your approach and the approach of mine using a custom module. Can you explain this?

Comment: drupal_set_message() is stored in global context and can't be part of the cache. What I'm suggesting would be cached together with the view. You could also create a views are plugin and display it above/below the form. See http://blog.studio.gd/node/16 or the related question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203438/create-a-custom-area-plugin